# Google play services keeps stopping, and it is much worse than normal

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, google-play-services, 8.1-oreo, samsung-galaxy-j7

My Samsung Galaxy J7 (2016 version) is constantly showing "Google play services keeps stopping" every 2~3 seconds. My device is running on android Oreo. I tried reverting back playstore to factory version, now I can't even enter playstore. It just keeps loading forever. I am unable to uninstall play services as well, neither can I delete the data. Yes I did try to deactivate the "find my device' option, but upon tapping "deactivate", the whole option gets greyed out and nothing happens.

I'm not being able to do anything on my phone, and its driving me crazy. Any sort of help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Try to activate Airplane mode. Hopefully this should reduce the error frequency. On newer devices there is the option to no longer show the error dialog. Looks like your device is too old for that feature or Samsung did not include it into their firmware.